# If statement defaulting to else despite parameters being met

Tags: html

I'm making a very simple text based game using html css and JavaScript. But I've ran into a problem where one of my if/else statement within a button will always default to the else statement despite the parameters being met for the if statement. (Sorry about the bad wording,I'm quite new to html and js.)

*Edit*I tried changing else to else if but it now won't display anything

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2 id="foe">-</h2>
<h3 id="foeDefence">-</h3>
<h3 id="playerAttack">-</h3>
<h1 id="out">-</h1>

<h1>▒▒▒▒▒▒         ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
<br>▒                                        ▒
<br>▒                                        ▒
<br>▒                                        ▒</h1>
<h1>                                       </h1>
<br><h1>▒                                        ▒
<br>▒                                        ▒
<br>▒                                        ▒
<br>▒▒▒▒▒▒         ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
</h1>
<button type="button" onclick='let foe = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
//document.getElementById("foe").innerHTML = foe
if (foe < 46){
    document.getElementById("foe").innerHTML = "slime"
    document.getElementById("foeDefence").innerHTML = "4"
}
else if (foe < 66){
    document.getElementById("foe").innerHTML = "goblin"
    document.getElementById("foeDefence").innerHTML = "6"
}
else if (foe < 100){
    document.getElementById("foe").innerHTML = "troll"
    document.getElementById("foeDefence").innerHTML = "10"
}
else if (foe == 100){
    document.getElementById("foe").innerHTML = "Rabid earthworm"
    document.getElementById("foeDefence").innerHTML = "0.000000000001"
}
'>Enter the next room</button>

<button type="button" onclick='
    let x = foeDefence;
    let y = playerAttack;
if (y > x){
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "get dogged on"
}
else{
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "You have succeeded in brutally dismembering the ravenous monster"
}
'>Attack!!!</button>
</body>
```

I tried this code, but even when y was greater than x, it still output the else.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why code is split up sorry about that

Comment: Here is how to format code blocks in a question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow . May I ask you for the full html and js code for more info?

Comment: We don’t know what those references are or their values. Tangential: It might be worth checking out a tutorial or two; there’s some recommendations that’ll make this easier to deal with.

Comment: May I ask where you got the pattern to put inline JavaScript like this in an onclick? Can't say I've seen this before.

Comment: Here I edited it to be the full code

Comment: And to awnser phix, w3schools

Answer (score 0):

The expression y > x is never true because neither y or x are provided values. You are declaring y and x but neither contain values. Both values are therefore `undefined`.

undefined > undefined is false.

Make sure you assign values to these.

Beyond that, I'd take this code and put it in a function and call that. Then you can really use variables properly for this use case.

Comment: I did assign them but I will try to take your advice and make this a function

Comment: In your updated question, I can't see you defining x or y. I see you are using x to refer to foeDefence but I can't see foeDefence defined of set a value in he updated question code. To be clear, foeDefence does not contain the value of the innerHtml.

You should either, show me the full code, or do some javaScript course on how and where variables are defined, assigned in a file.
Also if you console.log(x); and console.log(y);  just before if (y > x), you will see their values in the browser console.